# How to get a string from input box?

Tags: java, swing, joptionpane

How can I get a string from the user by using input box with `JOptionPane` method in Java? I know how to get `int` but I can't get `String` from user.

Comment: 1) Set or get? The title contradicts the text in the body of the question. 2) If 'get', look into the `JOptionPane.showInputDialog(..)` overloaded methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is quite straight forward. See below minimal example.

When user enters some text in the text field and clicks "OK" button, `showInputDialog()` method returns that text entered by the user. If user clicks "Cancel" button, `null` is returned.

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class InputDialog
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    String userInput = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "What is your name?", "Input", JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
    System.out.println("User input: " + userInput);
  }
}
```